# Get currently building object from custom InjectionFactory in Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

Is it possible, using a custom factory method, to get the resolving type's parent in Unity. I am trying to build a logger that has some context applied to it already regarding its parent object.

```
// ... other types being registered
container.RegisterType<ILogger>(new InjectionFactory(ResolveLogger));

// Custom factory method
private ILogger ResolveLogger(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // I want to know the type of the parent that requires the ILogger interface so that I can add it to my logging context (with Serilog):
    Type parentType = ???
    return Log.Logger.ForContext(parentType);
}
```

When I create an instance of a class, Serilog allows me to set a context for the logger in this manner:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public MyService(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger.ForContext(this.GetType());
    }
}
```

After that, all of the calls to `this.logger.Information("Hello World")` will include additional metadata showing the call was done in the MyService class.

I was trying to avoid having to remember to call `logger.ForContext(this.GetType())` in every class that consumes a logger by having Unity do the work for me.

Comment: Could you try to explain what you end goal is. Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: I've updated the question with my specific goal.

Comment: Not sure Unity provides that information. You could try to look into some custom resolver or custom policies or custom buildup. But I think Log4Net does what you want..

Answer (score 1):

I don't even think a custom policy would get you what you are after.  I'm not sure there is even a hook that gives you visibility into the "parent" type.  I could be wrong.  But here's an alternative solution and what I use.

You could use generics to get the calling type (similar to `ForContext` you mentioned, but a little more elegant).  And you could use [`[CallerMemberName]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the name of the calling member (method name, property name, etc.).

---

Like this...

```
public interface ILogger<T>
{
    void Write(string message, [CallerMemberName] string callingMethod = "");
}
```

---

And the Unity registration would be using open generics like this...

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(ConsoleLogger<>));
```

---

And here's an example usage...

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(ILogger<MyFileService> logger)
    {
        // Check for nulls, set to member variable, etc.
    }
}
```

---

But note that this does not work with static types as static types cannot be used as generic arguments (this hasn't been much of a problem for me because I try to avoid static types).

I've mocked up an example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/or0uIn).